# All Windows 10 1607 Computers Fail 1703 Update: Install Error 8000FFF

Tags: windows-10-v1703, wsus

I am trying to install the Feature Update 1703 through WSUS. Computers are at Windows 10 1607. I have approved the update through WSUS and it has downloaded the update and is set to be deployed. The computers can see the update and says it downloads the update. Then it says Preparing to Install and then says it failed to install with error 8000ffff. The WindowsUpdate Log gives me no real information other than that. Has anyone had this issue? I have googled all over for this issue but there isn't great information.

**EDIT:**  checked all the locations for logs and found the setup log here:

```
C:\Windows\Logs\MoSetup\BlueBox.log
```

All it says is that it tired to open update box.
Opening Box: `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\d159eb083e081bb92227c3bcd931d181\WindowsUpdateBox.exe`

Then gave this:

```
Opening Box Result [0x0]
```

Then it gives the 8000FFFF error.
There is no files like this:

```
C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther\setupact.log
C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther\miglog.xml
```

Comment: share the [log files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors#log-files) which are created during upgrade to 1703 from 1 device.

Comment: @magicandre1981 What log files are you talking about? The ELT files don't show much information. Other than it found the update and downloaded it and then fails. There are no Symbols for the GUID is it looking for.

Comment: Have you tried mounting the ISO and installing the update that way (as a RST)?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't have the ISO. I have the update through WSUS. I have tried looking in these areas. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/928901/log-files-that-are-created-when-you-upgrade-to-a-new-version-of-window There are still no logs there that have been updated to see anything.

Comment: So download the ISO and try installing the update as a test to rule out several possibilities

Comment: @Ramhound That is not going to be the answer for an entire enterprise.

Comment: I want all logs from **C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\Panther**

Comment: @magicandre1981 C:\$Windows.~BT\ does not exist

Comment: this is a hidden directory

Comment: @magicandre1981 I am showing hidden directories and files. There is no such directory.

Comment: @JukEboX It’s going to be required to verify what the problem is exactly.  I am not telling you to upgrade every machine like that just a single machine.

Comment: @Ramhound burned a disc this morning using the Media Creation Tool. Attempting the upgrade now. More information to come.

Comment: @Ramhound Was able to install 1703 with the DVD Image so it is definitely a WSUS issue.

Comment: ok, here I'm out. I have no real WSUS experience.